# zend redirect using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I want to redirect '/' or '/index' to '/user' action in zend2.
I googled it but still I haven't found a solution.

The htaccess code is:

```
SetEnv "APP_ENV" "developement"

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: You should do it via virtual host configuration, my opinion

Comment: virtual host is configured for other links but my requirement is just for this 1 url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me is:

```
SetEnv "APP_ENV" "developement"

RewriteEngine On 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^$ user [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: yes, It worked from me. It redirects to /user whenever the url is either '/' or '/index'

Comment: That is interesting because I don't see any rule for `/index` here.

Comment: **RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]** 
**RewriteRule ^$ user [R=301,L]** These 2 lines are used to make it work.

Comment: one is ignoring `index.php` for rewrite and second one is making landing page goto `/user`. Nothing specific for `/index` URI.

Comment: Yes and this is what I needed. It is more like static code only for /index but stay unaffected for /index/action